# Expanding JS for show on viewpoint

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the following script to change the class of different Div's as a user scrolls down the page (their are eight sections in total)

the trouble is, I can only get it to work on one section; if I copy the script eight times in only runs once. Could someone help me understand how to get it to work across every section.

The JS

```
$(function  () {

// define the isOnScreen plugin from http://jsfiddle.net/moagrius/wN7ah/
$.fn.isOnScreen = function() {
    var win = $(window);
    
    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft(),
        right: win.scrollLeft() + win.width(),
        bottom: win.scrollTop() + win.height()
    };
    
    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();
    
    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top ||     viewport.top > bounds.bottom)); 
};
   
// define throttling function for use in scroll event listener
// ref: http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/javascriptfunctionthrottlingan/
function throttle(delay, callback) {
    var previousCall = new Date().getTime();
    return function() {
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        if ((time - previousCall) >= delay) {
            previousCall = time;
            callback.apply(null, arguments);
        }
    };
}

// set up an event to listen for window scroll 4 times a second
$(window).on('scroll', throttle( 250, function () {

    // if #the-box is visible the call init functions and disable window scroll
    // event listener, as you only want to initialise the lightbox once
    if ( $(".two").isOnScreen() ) {
        
        // for demo purposes
        //alert('init');
        $(".two_sub").addClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        
        // call your init functions here
        //getThemenCount();
        //moveThemenAnimate();
        
        // turn off scroll listener
        $(window).off('scroll');



     }
    }));
});
```

the HMTL

```
<section class="one">
<div class="one_sub"></div>
<section class="two">
<div class="two_sub"></div>
</section>
<section class="three">
<div class="three_sub"></div>
</section>
<section class="four">
<div class="four_sub"></div>
</section>
```

I need it to work across every section (the JS was present on the existing site I'm trying to expand to more than one section (all four shown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're only checking the `.two` element. If the `isOnScreen` is implemented properly it should be able to target multiple elements and find the ones that trigger the `isOnScreen` function. Then instead of having very verbose classes like, `.two_sub` and `.three_sub`, rename the classes to `.sub` to make it a more generic element to find.

```
// set up an event to listen for window scroll 4 times a second
$(window).on('scroll', throttle( 250, function () {

    // if #the-box is visible the call init functions and disable window scroll
    // event listener, as you only want to initialise the lightbox once
    if ( $(".one, .two, .three, .four").isOnScreen() ) {
        
        // for demo purposes
        //alert('init');
        $(this).find(".sub").addClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        
        // call your init functions here
        //getThemenCount();
        //moveThemenAnimate();
        
        // turn off scroll listener
        // Improve the logic so that it will turn off when all elements are in view.
        // $(window).off('scroll');
     }

}));
```

But if you're in for an update then I would suggest a completely different method which improves performance and complexity. Enter the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). This API enables you to monitor elements that enter or leave the viewport and act upon when of the two happens. It doesn't use events and runs more efficient than listening for scroll and having to throttle every 250 milliseconds to check for the elements.

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
  // This loop is called every time an element enters or leaves the viewport.
  entries.forEach(function(entry) {
    // Is element in view?
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      // If so, find the sub element and add a class.
      $(entry.target).find(".sub").addClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
      // We no longer have to observe this element.
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
});

// Observe the elements with the classes below.
document.querySelectorAll(".one, .two, .three, .four").forEach(function(element) {
  observer.observe(element);
});
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll give both a go.

Comment: Both worked but  yes you're correct Intersection Observer API. is much easier!

Answer (score 1):

Hi man I made something for you, the problem is this `$(window).off('scroll');` this permit the event only run once. You cant off the event. If you want to use the event one time more.

Here is the fiddle with one example changing the background-color to black when the section enter on screen:

```html
<section class="one">
  <div class="one_sub" style="background-color: red; width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
</section><!-- first error-->
<section class="two">
  <div class="two_sub" style="background-color: green; width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
</section>
<section class="three">
  <div class="three_sub" style="background-color: blue; width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
</section>
<section class="four">
  <div class="four_sub" style="background-color: yellow; width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
</section>
<section class="five">
  <div class="five_sub" style="background-color: coral; width: 100%; heigth: 400px;"></div>
</section>
```

```js
// define the isOnScreen plugin from http://jsfiddle.net/moagrius/wN7ah/
$.fn.isOnScreen = function() {
    var win = $(window);
    
    var viewport = {
        top : win.scrollTop(),
        left : win.scrollLeft(),
        right: win.scrollLeft() + win.width(),
        bottom: win.scrollTop() + win.height()
    };
    
    var bounds = this.offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();
    
    return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top ||     viewport.top > bounds.bottom)); 
};
   
// define throttling function for use in scroll event listener
// ref: http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/javascriptfunctionthrottlingan/
function throttle(delay, callback) {
    var previousCall = new Date().getTime();
    return function() {
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        if ((time - previousCall) >= delay) {
            previousCall = time;
            callback.apply(null, arguments);
        }
    };
}

// set up an event to listen for window scroll 4 times a second
window.onscroll = throttle( 250, function () {

    // if #the-box is visible the call init functions and disable window scroll
    // event listener, as you only want to initialise the lightbox once
     
    if ( $(".one").isOnScreen() ) {
        
        // for demo purposes

        $(".one_sub").addClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".two_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".three_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".four_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        
        // call your init functions here
        //getThemenCount();
        //moveThemenAnimate();
        
        // turn off scroll listener
        //$(window).off('scroll');
        return;
    }
     
    if ( $(".two").isOnScreen() ) {
        
        // for demo purposes

        $(".one_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".two_sub").addClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".three_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".four_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        
        // call your init functions here
        //getThemenCount();
        //moveThemenAnimate();
        
        // turn off scroll listener
        //$(window).off('scroll');
        return;
    }
    
    if ( $(".three").isOnScreen() ) {
        
        // for demo purposes

        $(".one_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".two_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".three_sub").addClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".four_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        
        // call your init functions here
        //getThemenCount();
        //moveThemenAnimate();
        
        // turn off scroll listener
        //$(window).off('scroll');
        return;
    }
    
    if ( $(".four").isOnScreen() ) {
        
        // for demo purposes

        $(".one_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".two_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".three_sub").removeClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        $(".four_sub").addClass("animate__fadeInRightBig");
        
        // call your init functions here
        //getThemenCount();
        //moveThemenAnimate();
        
        // turn off scroll listener
        //$(window).off('scroll');
        return;
    }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8pu6f2s3/32/